# SQL IF Statement in Inner Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Three table image and parameter like below. I'm Having problems while building query. Exact result is not displaying in one query. I want to get information from master table.

In table Customer I'm filling data from Regular and Master and Regular is under Master Table. Iwant to joint the query below

**Query 1**

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
       Customer.RefId,
       Regular.LicenseId,
       Regular.ControlId,
       Master.MasterId,
       Master.FullName,
       Master.profile
FROM   Customer
       INNER JOIN Regular
               ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId
       INNER JOIN Master
               ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
       Customer.RefId,
       Master.FullName,
       Master.profile
FROM   Customer
       INNER JOIN Master
               ON Customer.RefId = Master.MasterId
```

**Result**

[image]

How can I get the both result in one query. I'm tired using different different statement. Can I get the solution for this...

Comment: What result you want ? Can you explain a bit more. It is unclear to understand from the post \

Comment: I want the FullName and profile from master table. customer table having mixed Record of Regular and Master. Regular.controlId = Master.MasterId

Comment: Herd to tell what you're looking for.  If you need to join to the same table twice, usually you can do it with a table alias.

Comment: Can you post your sample output

Comment: @Backtrack Result is above 1 Result. in short I want to join my both query

Comment: So, 1 Result  (first image ) is the o/p . Is my understanding correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` should include equal number of columns

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
       Customer.RefId,
       Regular.LicenseId,
       Regular.ControlId,
       Master.MasterId,
       Master.FullName,
       Master.profile
FROM   Customer
       INNER JOIN Regular
               ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId
       INNER JOIN Master
               ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
       Customer.RefId,
       '' LicenseId,
       '' ControlId,
       '' MasterId,
       Master.FullName,
       Master.profile
FROM   Customer
       INNER JOIN Master
               ON Customer.RefId = Master.MasterId
```

**UPDATE**

Declare a parameter to pass the query string(r% or m%)

```
-- DemoProc 'R'
CREATE PROCEDURE Demoproc @param VARCHAR(50)
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF( @param LIKE 'R%' )
        BEGIN
            SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
                   Customer.RefId,
                   Regular.LicenseId,
                   Regular.ControlId,
                   Master.MasterId,
                   Master.FullName,
                   Master.profile
            FROM   Customer
                   INNER JOIN Regular
                           ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId
                   INNER JOIN Master
                           ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId
        END
      ELSE IF( @param LIKE 'M%' )
        BEGIN
            SELECT Customer.CustomerId,
                   Customer.RefId,
                   '' LicenseId,
                   '' ControlId,
                   '' MasterId,
                   Master.FullName,
                   Master.profile
            FROM   Customer
                   INNER JOIN Master
                           ON Customer.RefId = Master.MasterId
        END
  END

GO
```

Comment: I got the both record in a table but this is not use full while binding gridview can you use If statement is this while inner join for example IF RefId like 'R%' then INNER JOIN Regular ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId or If RefId Like 'M%' then INNER JOIN Master ON Customer.RefId = Master.MasterId

Comment: Yes. You can join based on condition @skgacharya

Comment: I tried that but not getting the result by this statement

Comment: Letme try @skgacharya

Comment: Are you running this query in Stored procedure? @skgacharya

Comment: Yes this is a store procedure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67514/discussion-between-sarath-avanavu-and-skgacharya).

Comment: waiting in chat room are you there ?